# Show that if $AB=BA=0$ then $rank(A+B)=rank(A)+rank(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We are supposed to show that if $AB=BA=0$ then $rank(A+B)=rank(A)+rank(B)$

Maybe this fact help to answer the question:

$rank(A+B)\le rank(A)+rank(B)$ 
and
$rank(A)+rank(B)=dim(Im(B))$.

But I got stuck when trying to prove that $rank(A+B)\ge rank(A)+rank(B)$

Comment: It's not true. For $A$ with $A^2 = 0$, it would say $\operatorname{rank} (2A) = 2\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that the matrices are not zero for all elements?

Comment: @DanielFischer how can you believe for A with $A^2=0$ cannot satisfiying?

Answer (score 4):

Take
$$
A=B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $AB=BA=0$, but 
$$
1=rank(A+B)\neq rank(A)+rank(B)=2.
$$
So Daniel is right.